# Attempt at a larger form of int cannot multiple against itself

Tags: c++

Well, I was trying to work out a class to generate a larger form of int as a self taught excercise but I have a small problem where I cannot multiply my larger form against another larger form of the same type. It works fine multiplied against an int however. Can anyone spot where I went wrong?

```
//myint.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// starter file for MyInt class header

class MyInt{
    friend MyInt operator+(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend MyInt operator*(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend MyInt multiplyOneByMany(const MyInt& x, const char y);
    friend MyInt lshift(MyInt a, int k);
    friend bool operator<(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend bool operator>(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend bool operator<=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend bool operator>=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend bool operator==(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend bool operator!=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const MyInt &m);
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &input, MyInt &m);

public:
    MyInt(int n = 0); // first constructor
    MyInt(const char str[]); // second constructor
    MyInt(int size, char fill); // third constructor
    MyInt(const MyInt& s); // copy constructor
    ~MyInt(); // destructor
    MyInt& operator=(const MyInt& s); // assignment operator overload
    MyInt operator++(); // prefix
    MyInt operator++(int); // postfix
    char& operator [] (int index); // array accessor
    void reserve(int newCapacity);
    MyInt multiplyOneByMany(const MyInt& x, const char y);
    MyInt lshift(MyInt a, int k);

private:
    // member data (suggested: use a dynamic array to store the digits)
    int size;
    int capacity;
    char* array;
    char* newArray(int space);

};
```

the .cpp

```
// myint.cpp
#include "myint.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

// reverseString ---------------------------------------------------------
void reverseString (char *s) {
    char t, *d = &(s[strlen (s) - 1]);
    while (d > s) {
        t = *s;
        *s++ = *d;
        *d-- = t;
    }
}

int C2I(char c){
    // converts character into integer (returns -1 for error)
    if (c < '0' || c > '9'){
        return -1; // error
    }
    return (c - '0'); // success
}

char I2C(int x){
    // converts single digit integer into character (returns '\0' for error)
    if (x < 0 || x > 9){
        return '\0'; // error
    }
    return (static_cast<char>(x) + '0'); // success
}

// newArray() -------------------------------------------------------------
// Container space allocator
char* MyInt::newArray(int space){
    char* oldArray = 0;
    oldArray = new (nothrow) char[space];
    if (oldArray == 0){
        cout << "Failed!\n";
    }else{
        //cout << "Succeeded!\n";
    }
    return oldArray;
}

// reserve() request container size increase --------------------------------
void MyInt::reserve(int newCapacity){
    if(size > newCapacity){
        cout << "Error. Setting capacity smaller than current size\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(capacity == newCapacity){
        return;
    }else{
        if(capacity > newCapacity){
            return;
        }else{
            char* oldArr = array;
            array = newArray(newCapacity);
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                array[i] = oldArr[i];
            }
            capacity = newCapacity;
            delete [] oldArr;
        }
    }
}

// first constructor ------------------------------------------------------
// pass in int n and create object with it if >= 0
MyInt::MyInt(int n){
    if(n > 0){
        int len = 0;
        size = len;
        int x = n;
        while (n > 0) {
            n = n / 10;
            len++;
        }
        size = len;
        capacity = (len + 5);
        array = newArray(capacity);
        //5230/10^3
        int m = 0;
        for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            int y = pow(10, i); // y =10^3
            int z = x/y; //5620/100 = 56
            while(z > 10) {
                z = z % 10;
            }
            char newInt = I2C(z);
            array[i] = newInt; // array = ['5', '6', '2', '0']
        }
    }else{
        size = 1;
        capacity = 6;
        array = newArray(capacity);
        array[0] = '0';
    }
}

// second constructor -------------------------------------------------------
MyInt::MyInt(const char str[]){
    int length = strlen(str);
    char localstr[length];
    strcpy(localstr,str);
    bool badChars = false;
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
        if(localstr[i] < '0' || localstr[i] > '9'){
            badChars = true;
        }else{
        }
    }
    if (!badChars){
        size = length;
        capacity = length + 5;
        array = newArray(capacity);
        reverseString(localstr);
        strcpy(array, localstr);
    }else{
        size = 1;
        capacity = size +5;
        array = newArray(capacity);
        array[0] = '0';
    }
}

// third constructor -------------------------------------------------------
MyInt::MyInt(int size, char fill){
    this->size=size;
    capacity =size+5;
    array = newArray(capacity);
    for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++){
        array[i] = fill;
    }
}

// copy constructor --------------------------------------------------------
MyInt::MyInt(const MyInt& s){   
    size = s.size;
    capacity = s.capacity;
    array = new char[capacity];
    strcpy(array,s.array);
}

// destructor --------------------------------------------------------------
MyInt::~MyInt(){   
    if (array != 0){
        delete [] array;
    }
}

// assignment operator = ---------------------------------------------------
MyInt& MyInt::operator=(const MyInt& s){   
    if (this != &s){
        delete [] array;
        size = s.size;
        capacity = s.capacity;
        array = new char[capacity];
        strcpy(array,s.array);
    }
    return *this;
}

// prefix ++ --------------------------------------------------------------
MyInt MyInt::operator++(){   
    size = size + 1;
    return *this;
}

// postfix ++ -------------------------------------------------------------
MyInt MyInt::operator++(int){   
    MyInt temp = *this;
    size = size + 1;
    return temp;
}

// addition operator + ----------------------------------------------------
MyInt operator+(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
    MyInt s((x.size<y.size)?y:x); //array which is the size of larger of both arrays
    int remainder = 0, columnTotal = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i< s.size; i++){ //iterate from end to begin of array
        if(s.size == s.capacity){
            s.reserve(2*s.size + 1);
        }
        int operand1(0);
        int operand2(0);
        //if the summation is larger than 1 digit
        if (i < x.size) {
            operand1 = C2I(x.array[i]);
        }
        if (i < y.size) {
            operand2 = C2I(y.array[i]);
        }
        if((columnTotal = remainder + operand1 + operand2) > 9){
            remainder = columnTotal / 10; //store remainder
            columnTotal = columnTotal % 10;
        }else{
            remainder = 0;
        }
        char convertChar = I2C(columnTotal);
        s.array[i] = convertChar;
    }
    if(remainder > 0){
        if(s.size == s.capacity){
            s.reserve(2*s.size + 1);
        }
        s.size++;
        s.array[i] = I2C(remainder);
    }
    return s;
}

// lshift() ---------------------------------------------------------------
MyInt lshift(MyInt a, int k) { // returns a shifted left by k digits
    MyInt c(a);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<a.size ; i++) {
        if(c.size == c.capacity){
            c.reserve(2*c.size + 1);
        }
        c[i+k] = a[i];
    }
    if (k==0) {
        c.array[c.size] = '0';
    }else if (k>0){
        c.array[0] = '0';
    }
    c.size++;
    int j=3;
    return c;
}

// multiplication overload * nested loop fxn---------------------------------
MyInt multiplyOneByMany(const MyInt& x, const char y){
    MyInt s(x);
    int remainder = 0, columnTotal = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<x.size; i++){ //iterate from end to begin of array
        if(s.size == s.capacity){
            s.reserve(2*s.size + 1);
        }
        //if the summation is larger than 1 digit
        if((columnTotal = remainder + C2I(x.array[i])*C2I(y)) > 9){
            remainder = columnTotal / 10; //store remainder
            columnTotal = columnTotal % 10;
        }else {
            remainder = 0;
        }
        char convertChar = I2C(columnTotal);
        s.array[i] = convertChar;
    }
    if(remainder > 0){
        if(s.size == s.capacity){
            s.reserve(2*s.size + 1);
        }
        s.size++;
        s.array[i] = I2C(remainder);
    }
    return s;
}

// operator* -----------------------------------------------------------------
MyInt operator*(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){
    MyInt c(0);
    MyInt maxDigitOperand ( x.size > y.size ? x : y);
    MyInt minDigitOperand ( x.size >= y.size ? y : x);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < minDigitOperand.size; i++) {
        if(c.size == c.capacity){
            c.reserve(2*c.size + 1);
        }
        if (C2I(maxDigitOperand.array[i]) != 0) { //if it is zero, nothing to do
            c = c + lshift(multiplyOneByMany(maxDigitOperand,minDigitOperand.array[i]), i);
        }
    }
    if (minDigitOperand.size == 1){
        c.size--;
    }
    return c;
}

// less than operator < ------------------------------------------------------
bool operator<(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){   
    int tempSize = max(x.size, y.size);
    if(x.size < y.size){
        return true;
    }else if(x.size == y.size){
        if(x.array[0] < y.array[0]){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// greater than operator > ---------------------------------------------------
bool operator>(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){   
    return (y < x);
}

// less than or equal to operator <= ------------------------------------------
bool operator<=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){   
    return (x < y || x == y);
}

// greater than or equal to operator >= -------------------------------------
bool operator>=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){   
    return (x > y || x == y);
}

// equality operator == -------------------------------------------------------
bool operator==(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){   
    if (x.size != y.size){
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size; ++i){
        if (x.array[i] != y.array[i]){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// not equal operator != ------------------------------------------------------
bool operator!=(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y){   
    return !(x == y);
}

// extraction operator << -----------------------------------------------------
ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const MyInt &m){   
    for(int i = m.size-1;i>=0; --i){
        output << m.array[i];
    }
    return output;
}

// insertion operator >> -----------------------------------------------------
istream &operator >> (istream &input, MyInt &m){   
    char c;
    bool startedReading = false;
    int arraySize = 0;
    char* oldArray; //increases in size by 1
    //each time digit read in
    while (true) {
        c = input.get();
        //skip over leading whitespace
        if (c == ' '){
            if (startedReading) {
                break;
            }else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (c >= '0' || c <= '9') {
            startedReading = true;
            arraySize++;
            //copy the current digit read in from input
            //stream
            //create new array that holds one more element
            //and copy previously read digits into it
            char* emptyArray = m.newArray(arraySize); //2
            if (arraySize > 1) {
                strcpy(emptyArray, oldArray);
            }
            oldArray = emptyArray; //1
            oldArray[arraySize -1 ] = c;
        }
        char nextChar = input.peek();
        if (nextChar == '\n') {
            input.get(); //consume newline
            break;
        }
        if (nextChar < '0' || nextChar > '9'){
            break;
        }
    }
    //oldArray at this point contains "12345"
    if (arraySize > 0){
        m.capacity = arraySize + 5;
        m.array = m.newArray(m.capacity);
        m.size = arraySize;
        reverseString(oldArray);
        strcpy(m.array, oldArray);
    }
    return input;
}

// operator[] - accessor -----------------------------------------------------
char& MyInt::operator[](int index){
    if(index >= capacity){
        cout << "Accessing out of bounds" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

and the main I was testing against (with the problem section commented out)

```
// main.cpp -- Bob Myers
//
// Driver program to demonstrate the behavior of the MyInt class
// 
// You can add more tests of your own, or write other drivers to test your
// class

#include <iostream>
#include "myint.h"

using namespace std;

MyInt Fibonnaci(MyInt num);

int main()
{

  // demonstrate behavior of the two constructors and the << overload

  MyInt x(12345), y("9876543210123456789"), r1(-1000), r2 = "14H67", r3;
  char answer;
  cout << "Initial values: \nx = " << x << "\ny = " << y
       << "\nr1 = " << r1 << "\nr2 = " << r2 << "\nr3 = " << r3 << "\n\n";

  // demonstrate >> overload

  cout << "Enter first number: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "Enter second number: ";
  cin >> y;

  cout << "You entered:\n";
  cout << "  x = " << x << '\n';
  cout << "  y = " << y << '\n';

  // demonstrate assignment =
  cout << "Assigning r1 = y ...\n";
  r1 = y;
  cout << "  r1 = " << r1 << '\n';

  // demonstrate comparison overloads
  if (x < y)    cout << "(x < y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x > y)    cout << "(x > y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x <= y)   cout << "(x <= y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x >= y)   cout << "(x >= y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x == y)   cout << "(x == y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x != y)   cout << "(x != y) is TRUE\n";

  // demonstrating + and * overloads
  r1 = x + y;
  cout << "The sum (x + y) = " << r1 << '\n';
//  r2 = x * y;
//  cout << "The product (x * y) = " << r2 << "\n\n";
  cout << "The sum (x + 12345) = " << x + 12345 << '\n';
  cout << "The product (y * 98765) = " << y * 98765 << '\n';

  // create Fibonacci numbers (stored as MyInts) using +
  cout << "\nAssuming that the Fibonnaci sequence begins 1,1,2,3,5,8,13..."
       << "\n\nThe 10th Fibonnaci number   = " << Fibonnaci(10)
       << "\n\nThe 100th Fibonnaci number  = " << Fibonnaci(100)
       << "\n\nThe 1000th Fibonnaci number = " << Fibonnaci(1000)
       << "\n\nThe 2000th Fibonnaci number = " << Fibonnaci(2000)
       << "\n\n";
}

MyInt Fibonnaci(MyInt num)
{
   MyInt n1 = 1, n2 = 1, n3;
   for(int i = 2; i < num; i++)
   {
    n3 = n1 + n2;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
   }
   return n2;
}
```

It runs just fine until the r2 = x * y get addded back in, then it complains about accessing out of bounds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this program one line at a time, while monitoring the values of all variables and seeing how they change, with each line of the code, what did you see?

Comment: Something is wrong.  It says: "You entered:  x = 1  y = 2  ... The sum (x + y) = 3  The product (x * y) = 4" but 1*2 is not 4

Comment: The complier I am using doesn't have a line-by-line option that I am aware of

Comment: Careful  with `int y = pow(10, i);` You think you'd get (and usually do get) 100 if `i` = 2, but you could get a close-enough 99.999999999 that truncates to 99. If you want integers, you're often better off multiplying integers than trying to take a short-cut through floating point with `pow`.

Comment: Sam's not talking about the compiler, he's talking about the debugging utility that almost always comes with a the compiler these days. A debugger without a single step option would be nearly useless, so trust me, you've got one.

Comment: The error it gave me was quite clear.  `istream &operator >> (istream &input, MyInt &m)` declares  `char* oldArray;` but doesn't point it anywhere at all.  Then `strcpy(emptyArray, oldArray);` tries to copy data from a pointer that doesn't point anywhere.  No wonder it explodes.

Comment: Sounds like I need to quit using an online one then

Comment: Ah. There we go. Yeah. Online dev environments are second (if not third) class citizens. They'll get better, but as of today, you're better off doing the heavy work on a computer you completely control with the tools installed on the computer. If you need to submit to an online tool, do as much of the work where you've got the best tools and finish up on the online tool when you have most of the bugs worked out. Do the same if you find yourself writing software for any system that you can't easily debug on, like the MCU in an iToaster.

Comment: There are still useful debugging techniques even when you are using an online compiler.  All you need to do is make your program output any values that you want to examine, add messages to functions or branch points you want to see being hit, add counters or other metadata, etc.  And then just run your program.  Iterate on this until you isolate the incorrect code and fix it.  But ideally, you should develop locally, preferably in a decent IDE that allows you to set breakpoints and step through the code line by line easily.

Comment: *"it complains about [X]"* -- please do not paraphrase error messages unless you know exactly what they say and how to fix them. Every paraphrase leaves out details, and if you do not fully understand an error message, paraphrasing it is likely to leave out important details. Copy the message (as text) into your question.

Comment: *"Can anyone spot where I went wrong?"* -- possibly, but there is too much noise for it to be worth my time. Please reduce your code to a [mre]. The example does not need to be able to multiply correctly; it only needs to be able to reproduce your error. *It would also help if you were to identify the line that triggers the error (a debugger is useful for this).*

Comment: @AndrewKennedy `char* array;` -- Save yourself a lot of trouble and use `std::vector<char>`.  Then that assignment operator, copy constructor, and destructor you wrote becomes unnecessary.  If you want to build furniture, you don't create your own hammer and screwdriver, you get them from the hardware store.  If you want a dynamic array, use `std::vector`, and not try to do all of this work yourself.  If your goal is to write a big integer class, why get bogged down by trying to implement dynamic arrays?

Comment: @AndrewKennedy In addition, the *less* code you need to write, the more easier it is for the problem to be debugged.  Right now, you have to test copying, assignment, and destruction to make sure *you* didn't introduce bugs by trying to implement a home-made dynamic array class.  Using ready-made components such as `std::vector` makes the job much easier.  You also would eliminate the need for those other member variables, as a `std::vector` knows its sizey by calling the requisite member functions (`vector::size()`)